# How to define mapped type for method return types in typescript 4.5.4?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

In typescript 4.4.4 this code compiled fine:

```js
/**
 * type to get only those properties that are functions
 */
type FunctionProperties<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any) => any ? P : never;
}[keyof T];

type ReturnTypeOfMethod<T, K extends FunctionProperties<T>> = ReturnType<T[K]>;
```

see [Playground 4.4.4 example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUBO7I5oQDOAPACoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANpZSoJQDWEEOgBmUcgF0AXGM7ioEAB7AICACbEoACgB0ugIY4A5sWl6EIAJS1qZkFAD8ULtIQQAbhBwBuFgF92AkKiEj7MLKCQUABKEMBwOAjk4BAA8sIAsrEAFuiqFAA0UADS8koq6rCIKBjYeAREZFTUdDFxCUmQFOxF4pShLAD0AFRDLFBDUACiABoAgulYADKTY0MDLEgANnrEGuQkwADC27sMY1DEwDg8hgBqepsAhNKX1wiG-awXVzcwKJpWJhfNg4WLxXgAcj0ACMkBDQmxfCxzgg4ABbaGeP7ATQ8MBwYAudGYnCA84gsEJbgIfHABFQJHMRnhZLRSmJZIAOWJnlobLaHMgaUywByeX2l2OO2IhQhqIxWJQEL6QA)

But the same code fails to compile in typescript 4.5.4 - see [Playground 4.5.4 example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUBO7I5oQDOAPACoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANpZSoJQDWEEOgBmUcgF0AXGM7ioEAB7AICACbEoACgB0ugIY4A5sWl6EIAJS1qZkFAD8ULtIQQAbhBwBuFgF92AkKiEj7MLKCQUABKEMBwOAjk4BAA8sIAsrEAFuiqFAA0UADS8koq6rCIKBjYeAREZFTUdDFxCUmQFOxF4pShLAD0AFRDLFBDUACiABoAgulYADKTY0MDLEgANnrEGuQkwADC27sMY1DEwDg8hgBqepsAhNKX1wiG-awXVzcwKJpWJhfNg4WLxXgAcj0ACMkBDQmxfCxzgg4ABbaGeP7ATQ8MBwYAudGYnCA84gsEJbgIfHABFQJHMRnhZLRSmJZIAOWJnlobLaHMgaUywByeX2l2OO2IhQhqIxWJQEL6QA)

```
Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'T[FunctionProperties<T>]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type 'T[T[keyof T] extends (...args: any) => any ? keyof T : never]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
      Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
        Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
          Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
```

The strange thing is that the `ReturnTypeNumber` type still shows the expected type (`number` in this example).
Any idea why this does not work anymore or how to fix this (using `@ts-ignore` is **not** a fix)?

Comment: Repeating the condition seems to help: `type ReturnTypeOfMethod<T, K extends FunctionProperties<T>> = T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> : never;` No idea what feature caused change in behaviour - perhaps https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46429

Comment: I filed a bugreport: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite verbose since you have to repeat the condition, but it would suppress the error.

```
type ReturnTypeOfMethod<T, K extends FunctionProperties<T>> =
  T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> : never;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this was a [documented breaking change](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5/#restrictions-on-assignability-to-conditional-types) in version 4.5:

> Restrictions on Assignability to Conditional Types
> TypeScript no longer allows types to be assignable to conditional types that use infer, or that are distributive. Doing so previously often ended up causing major performance issues. For more information, see the specific change on GitHub.

So we really need the more verbose version as mentioned in [Stonehearts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70533544/1041641)